# Even if an intruder aircraft isn't equipped with TCAS, can I detect them with my TCAS?

Tags: transponder, tcas

[image: excerpt from FAA's introduction to TCAS]

I'm wondering about the TCAS operation concept.

If aircraft "A" is equipped with TCAS I or TCAS II equipment,
and aircraft "B" isn't equipped with either TCAS transponder or antenna,

then can aircraft "A" receive a "traffic adivsory" (TA) when aircraft "B" comes close?

When I check the 'FAA's introduction to TCAS' Table 1(6p),(see the picture)
if aircraft "A" is equipped with TCAS, then it always provides a "TA" in any situation.

Did I understand that correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Aircraft "B" has to be equipped with at least a Mode A transponder for the TCAS in aircraft "A" to provide a Traffic Advisory to its pilot.

The way TCAS detects nearby aircraft is by interrogation their transponder. So if the other aircraft ("B") does not have any transponder (A, A/C, or S) then TCAS does not work.

Comment: If "B" is equipped "MODE S" but without TCAS unit and Antenna, "A" can detect the "B" by TCAS system?

Comment: @PARKMIN yes, if "B" has a functioning Mode-S transponder, the TCAS on "A" will detect "B" and provide both TAs and RAs.